# BTRFS bad tree block start

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, raid, lvm, btrfs

First some background on my setup.
I have 7 Hard Drives in a raid 5 (I know, move to raid 6, but not the issue here) array. On top of that, I run LVM, with a partition for btrfs. 
BTRFS is at version 3.1245. Kernel is 3.13.0-53-generic. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

I just finished migrating that data from ext4 via a series of lvextend/reduce from the EXT4 to the btrfs partitions. I was using a temporary drive in the LVM to give me the space to move data between the two partitions in larger chunks.

Over the weekend it finally finished and I was ready to delete the EXT4 partition and remove the temporary drive.

I reduced the btrfs size using the command twice (to be sure that I had plenty of blank space at the end):

```
btrfs filesystem resize -950G
```

In my haste (haste made lots of waste...) I typed the command:

`lvreduce -L 950G /dev/bigdisk/btrfs`

instead of

`lvreduce -L -950G /dev/bigdisk/btrfs`

When I tried to mount the file system I got:

```
wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/bigdisk-btrfs...
```

dmesg gave me:

```
btrfs bad tree block start 12460867831478107890 3823471755264
btrfs bad tree block start 13567085538622844823 3823471755264
btrfs bad tree block start 12460867831478107890 3823471755264
btrfs bad tree block start 13567085538622844823 3823471755264
btrfs: failed to recover balance
btrfs: open_ctree failed
```

In my panic when I realized it wouldn't mount, I ran:

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/bigdisk/btrfs
```

which didn't fix anything. Googling (should have done that first), lead me to the vgcfgrestore command, which I ran, found the backup from before my 950G screw-up and restored:

```
vgcfgrestore -f [Filename here] -v /dev/bigdisk
```

still no love, same error messages.

I tried mounting with the recovery option:

```
mount -orecovery,ro /dev/bigdisk/btrfs
```

same errors

I ran:

```
btrfs rescue super-recover -v /dev/bigdisk/btrfs
```

which returns all good, no bad. "All supers are valid, no need to recover"

I ran the chunk-recover last night in hopes, which I just cleared from my screen while preparing this message :(, but it stated that it found a bunch of good chunks, but couldn't repair. I'll re-run it and post the output here as soon as it finishes.
I ran:
    btrfs rescue chunk-recover -v /dev/bigdisk/btrfs

Is there anything else I can do? I have backups of my important files, but this array included rips of my DVD/Blurays, which we have quite a few. The idea of re-ripping these is making me very sad, it'll take months. The disk array is rather large so making a full disk backup is impractical (partition size is ~12TB)

Comment: the btrfs rescue chunk-recover -v /devbigdisk/btrfs yeild:
Total Chunks:   9020
  Heathy:       9020
  Bad:  0

Orphan Block Groups:

Orphan Device Extents:
Check tree block failed, want=2260410597376, have=9707841835804020818
Check tree block failed, want=2260410597376, have=9707841835804020818
[SNIP]
read block failed check_tree_block
open with broken chunk error
Fail to recover the chunk tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those that find this later, it turned out that upgrading the kernel to 3.19 fixed everything. I upgraded, rebooted and the disk mounted on boot without errors. BTRFS check came back OK, as did the scrub.